# In an array with objects, check if a key exists in any of those objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, and need to see if a key exists in any of them. Here is what I am doing now:

```
const arr = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 }]
arr.map(o => o.foo && true).includes(true)
// true
```

Is there any better/more accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the **[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** function:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, foo: 'bar' },
  { id: 2 }
];

var result = arr.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('foo'));
console.log("The array contains an object with a 'foo' property: " + result);

var result = arr.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('baz'));
console.log("The array contains an object with a 'baz' property: " + result);
```

Comment: This will not work if searched property value is falsy (e.g `foo: 0`)

Comment: @bartekfr in my use case it's not an issue (it will always be an integer above 0), but kudos for pointing that out.

Comment: Updated the answer. It originally looked like the OP was looking for "truthy" property values, not that he was looking for the existence  of the property.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 }]
result = arr.some(o => 'foo' in o)
console.log(result)
```

### Difference between `every()` and `some()`

- every:

It will check for the existence of the given key on **all** object, and return false if not all of them have this key.

- some:

It will check if **at least one** object has that key and if there is it already returns true.

Answer (score 4):

```
const arr = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 }]
var result = arr.some((value, index) => {
    return value.hasOwnProperty('bar')
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a true/false to determine if the element is in there, use 'some'. It returns true/false.

```
const arr = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 }];
var key = 'foo';
var isInArray= arr.some(function(val, i) {
    return val[i][key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 }],
    result = arr.some(o => 'foo' in o);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead?