# How to check if the children exist in arrray of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to check if the children exists in the array of objects using javascript. the datastructure looks like below,

[image]

suppose i have the data stored in variable arr_obj then i have tried using

```
if (arr_obj && arr_obj[0].children && arr_obj[0].children.length > 0) {
    console.log("children exists")
}  
if (arr_obj && !arr_obj[0].children) {
    console.log("children doesnt exist")
}
```

when children array is 0 the condition (arr_obj && !arr_obj[0].children) throws error "cannot read property children of undefined" could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `if(arrayName[0].children){. . . }` To check each array item put this line in a loop that iterates the entire array and replace `0` with your loop counter.

Comment: thanks i want to check if the children exists or not...meaning children.length === 0 means no children array present. but not working in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an array with objects, check if a key exists in any of those objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074997/in-an-array-with-objects-check-if-a-key-exists-in-any-of-those-objects)

Comment: Can I have sample data ?

Comment: how about `if (arr_obj && arr_obj[0] && arr_obj[0].children ...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited Also you should check the array first (**arr_obj  && arr_obj.length > 0 && arr_obj[0].hasOwnProperty('children') && arr_obj[0].children.length > 0 )** then true else false.

If i understand your question correctly. I just make the object as you describe above. I think with filter inside a filter or a map or a reduce you can do your job. You should see why to use what in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). This returns a boolean. If true element exist if false its not. The first console check if it has a specific children, and the second console check if it has children as you describe above.

```js
var obj = [];

var parent1 = {};

parent1.children = [];

parent1.children.push({
  name: 'parent1_somename1'
})

parent1.children.push({
  name: 'parent1_somename2'
});
obj.push(parent1);

var parent2 = {};

parent2.children = [];

parent2.children.push({
  name: 'parent2_somename1'
})

parent2.children.push({
  name: 'parent2_somename2'
})

obj.push(parent2);

function checkIfExists(arrList, searchedItem) {
  var results = arrList.filter(function(element) {
    var resultsChild = element.children.filter(function(childElement) {
      return childElement.name === searchedItem;
    });

    if (resultsChild.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })

  return results;
}


function checkIfItHasChildren(arrList) {
  var results = arrList.map(function(element) {
    return element.children.length > 0;

    if (results.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })

  return results;
}


// Check if specific children exists
if (obj && checkIfExists(obj, 'parent2_somename2').length > 0) {
  console.log("children exists")
} else {
  console.log("children doesnt exist")
}



// Check if array has childrens
if (obj && checkIfItHasChildren(obj).length > 0) {
  console.log("It has children")
} else {
  console.log("It doesnt has children")
}
```